# Input with overlapping elements inside a FrameLayout

Tags: android-layout, unity-game-engine, android, android-framelayout

I have a game (Unity3d) that is running on Android where its View is contained in a FrameLayout. The game view covers the entire screen.

I am adding (in code) another view next to this view another button view (the 2 views overlap - see images below).

The button does not receive any input.

According to the documentation for FrameLayout, it is advisable to use a single element under it, but multiple views are also possible.

Why does my button not receive any input?

Attaching the view state as captured in Eclipse.[image]